# How can I manage list height?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

[image]

Hello Stackoverflowers,

This image is showing product image and its description in list item(In `ul li`).

I am trying to manage the height of description same as product image's height.

Means: In Image,

For example: In "Accufitness Accumeasure Body Fat Caliper" Product:

I want to show the product description from first `li` to the third or fourth `li` [depending upon image height(Note: each images have fixed height)] and remaining `li` would be hidden. I want to have a "View more" link to display the remaining list. When user clicks on "View More" link, hidden list should be displayed and when they click  "Less" link, list(remaining `li` elements) should be hidden.

So, how can I manage the description height according as image height using jquery or can you suggest other ways?

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you right. I think you should but the list into a `div`, then give it the same `height` then the image and set `overflow` to `hidden`.

Now you can use jQuery to change the size of the `div` when the user clicks on the "View More" link.

Have no time to test  it yet, but I hope this can get you a bit further.

Answer (score 0):

Hypothetically you can create a div inside the li that has its height fixed at the image's height.
You could do this either with javascript by adding some script in the body's onload event, or as a php variable that is echoed into the html.

Either way, you would need to hide the overflow with css (overflow: hidden).

Then, once someone clicks "more", you can remove the fixed height by javascript and set the overflow style to visible.

Answer (score 0):

Add your list inside a div like this and add a button.

```
<div class="container">
<ul>
    <li>Here is some text, Here is some text</li>
    <li>Here is some text, Here is some text</li>
    <li>Here is some text, Here is some text</li>
    <li>Here is some text, Here is some text</li>
    <li>Here is some text, Here is some text</li>
    <li>Here is some text, Here is some text</li>
    <li>Here is some text, Here is some text</li>
    <li>Here is some text, Here is some text</li>
    <li>Here is some text, Here is some text</li>
    <li>Here is some text, Here is some text</li>
</ul>

</div><input type="button" class="seemorelinks" value="see more" onclick="$('.container').height('100%'); this.style.display='none';" />
```

Add this to your css

```
.container{ position:relative; height:40px; overflow:hidden;}​
```

Working fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/hBjmU/25/

Comment: Hi Ashwin, 
Thanks a lot, I am try to giving vote you but my reputation is less than 15. I will vote you once I reached to 15.

Comment: Why not mark my answer? You will see a "tick" mark on the left side of my answer, if I solved your problem tick on it.